# Powershell: Formatting Select -Index array

Tags: powershell

I am trying to come up with a good way to format the output of a Parsed Line, using the following data as one of the lines I am actually searching for in order to parse out some of the data.

```
#Data from my File
2014-07-24 19:30:23 IP.ADD.RESS.# GET /:8888/xxx/update/status/CheckingForUpdates - 80 - 192.168.x.x - 400 0 0 15
```

So what I am doing, is searching a large file for lines such as this.  I am actually searching for the keyword of CheckingForUpdates, and then parting out the "xxx" and "192.168.x.x" by doing the following select-string line.

```
Select-String -path $FileLocation -Pattern "CheckingForUpdates" -AllMatches |
%{$_ -split"/"} | %{$_ -split"- "} | Select -Index 2,7
```

With this I will get an output of:

```
xxx
192.168.x.x
```

So my question is, would anybody know of a way I could create an easy to read format when I am dealing with 100's of outputs from the actual file I am using?  What I am hoping for is

Item xxx is using and IP Address of 192.168.x.x

I tried a Write-Output and was unsuccessful due to trying to use a Select -Index twice in a single line.  Powershell doesn't seem to like that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample data it would appear you get a string array output. In my answer i assign that string array to a variable and format the output using `-f` format parameter.

```
$data = "2014-07-24 19:30:23 IP.ADD.RESS.# GET /:8888/xxx/update/status/CheckingForUpdates - 80 - 192.168.x.x - 400 0 0 15"
$strings = $data | Select-String -Pattern "CheckingForUpdates" -AllMatches |
%{$_ -split"/"} | %{$_ -split"- "} | Select -Index 2,7
"Item {0} is using and IP Address of {1}" -f $strings[0],$strings[1]
```

Which gives us the output of:

```
$data = "2014-07-24 19:30:23 IP.ADD.RESS.# GET /:8888/xxx/update/status/CheckingForUpdates - 80 - 192.168.x.x - 400 0 0 15"
$strings = $data | Select-String -Pattern "CheckingForUpdates" -AllMatches |
%{$_ -split"/"} | %{$_ -split"- "} | Select -Index 2,7

Item xxx is using and IP Address of 192.168.x.x
```

While we did not have to use the `-f` it certainly cleans up the code to make it easier to read. More information about it can be found [here](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/powershell-abcs-f-is-for-format-operator)